# 'conditionField == orders[0][0]': The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([docDate]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where()

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have the following code

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('product')
        .where('userId',isNotEqualTo: currentUser.uid) // userId is String field
        .orderBy('docDate',descending: true) // docDate is Timestamp 
        .get();
```

so i am trying to get data based on those doc that not `NotEqualTo` `currentUser.uid` and go on to get newest `docDate`(which is Timestamp )

error message :

> Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 492 pos 13: 'conditionField == orders[0][0]': The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([docDate]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where()

Comment: Have you checked the **[Query limitations](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#query-limitations)** ? You have to split that query with also considering the **[Limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations:~:text=If%20you%20include%20a%20filter%20with%20a%20range%20comparison%20\(%3C%2C%20%3C%3D%2C%20%3E%2C%20%3E%3D\)%2C%20your%20first%20ordering%20must%20be%20on%20the%20same%20field).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `userId`, you first need to order on that field. So:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('product')
    .orderBy('userId')
    .where('userId',isNotEqualTo: currentUser.uid)
    .orderBy('docDate',descending: true)
    .get();
```

This also means that the results will be ordered on `userId` first, and only then on `docDate`. So most likely you will need to re-order the results in your application code to be ordered only on `docDate`. There is no workaround for this.

Comment: thanks i also used the following and it worked as expected FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('product')
    .where('userId',isNotEqualTo: currentUser.uid)
    .orderBy('userId')
    .orderBy('docDate',descending: true)
    .get();

do i am doing good here ?

Comment: i was delay the vote till after my second question ,  thanks anyway for your awesome help